# Spring boot not able to refer a node in YAML file. No such property

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot, yaml

Here is how the YAML file looks. What I am trying to do is refer the `databaseHostURL`.

```
spring:
   profiles: default

databaseHostURL: localhost:3306

   datasource:
      driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      url: jdbc:mysql://${databaseHostURL}/mydatabase
```

Here is the error on Spring bootRun.

```
6:20:06 PM: Executing external task 'bootRun'...
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processResources'.
> Could not copy file '/com/home/users/Test/src/main/resources/application.yml' to '/com/home/users/Test/build/resources/main/application.yml'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.589 secs
No such property: databaseHostURL for class: SimpleTemplateScript7
6:20:07 PM: External task execution finished 'bootRun'.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to see your build.gradle file.
Based on the failure you are seeing,
I am guessing the "processResources" closure in your build.gradle is not empty,
and I am also guessing it looks something like this:

```
processResources {
    expand( project.properties )
}
```

The expand() is attempting to replace what it thinks are properties in your application.yml with their values, and when it sees the ${databaseHostUrl}, it tries to replace it with the value of that property - except that property is not set, so you get that error message:

```
No such property: databaseHostURL for class: SimpleTemplateScript7
```

If databaseHostURL is indeed a property you are trying to reference from the [Gradle environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-application-info-automatic-expansion-gradle), then you need to make sure it is defined there somewhere.

On the other hand, if databaseHostURL is a [Spring property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html), maybe set using an environment value, then I suggest you try commenting out the processResources block and see if that lets your build get past the processResources task and solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you're adding the property in the middle, between Spring and datasource.

Try adding the property before Spring tag.

```
databaseHostURL: localhost:3306
spring:
   profiles: default

   datasource:
      driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      url: jdbc:mysql://${databaseHostURL}/mydatabase
```